# SQL: getting sum of amounts of multiple rows in single table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my Table (invoice_payments):

[image: invoice_payments table]

I want to get rows grouped by `invoice_id` with sum of amount with specific condition.
My SQL query:

```
select invoice_id,  (select sum(invoice_payments.amount)  from invoice_payments where
invoice_payments.type!='Store') as total_paid, type from invoice_payments where
invoice_payments.type!='Store' group by invoice_id
```

I am getting this result:

[image: My Query Result]

As you can see this is wrong. Please someone help/suggest a solution. I really appreciate any reply.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get the second select, why are you non just doing something like `select invoice_id, sum(invoice_payments.amount) as total_paid, type from invoice_payments where
invoice_payments.type!='Store' group by type, invoice_id` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  invoice_id,  sum(invoice_payments.amount)  
from    invoice_payments 
where   invoice_payments.type!='Store'
group   by invoice_id.
```

Please post the expected output if the above query satisfy the needs.

Comment: What about this query? How can I fix this query?

`select invoice_id, sum(invoice_payments.amount) as total_paid, sum(case when type='Store' then invoice_payments.amount else 0 end ) as total_balance,  type from invoice_payments where invoice_payments.type!='Store' group by type, invoice_id`

Comment: @Maria. in the above qry the total_balance always results 0.what is the need of it?

Comment: why will it be 0 always? I need total_paid and total_balance both

Comment: you are filtering by invoice_payments.type!='Store' , so it will fetch only the type other than store. And in the case statement you   given as "when type='Store' then invoice_payments.amount" .

Comment: ok but I also need amount with type='store as a field, How can I acheive that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression inside the `sum` function:

```
SELECT   invoice_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN type != 'Store' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_paid
FROM     invoice_payments
GORUP BY invoice_id
```

Comment: What about this query? How can I fix this query? 
`select invoice_id, sum(invoice_payments.amount) as total_paid, sum(case when type='Store' then invoice_payments.amount else 0 end ) as total_balance, type from invoice_payments where invoice_payments.type!='Store' group by type, invoice_id`